# How many "blocking" pieces do I need for a finished basement wall?

Tags: basement-refinishing

I'm going to start finishing my basement. For the walls that run parallel to the floor joists, I'll need to install "blocking" pieces, for the top sill to be nailed to. Is there a general rule on how far apart they should be placed, or how many will be needed for a wall of "n" feet?

This isn't for additional bracing of the floor, just solely to have something that the top sill plate can be secured to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a single top plate I don’t like to go further than 8’. For a double top plate I go 12’.

If the wall is by a bathroom that’s going to have plumbing pipes drilled through the top plates, then I’d add one block by the holes.

Answer (score 4):

I do mine about every 16 inches.

[image]